# MEF Error message - VS2010

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, mef

Can anybody help me with explaining this error message please:

```
system.componentmodel.composition.changerejectedexception

The composition remains unchanged. The changes were rejected because of the following error(s): The composition produced a single composition error. 
The root cause is provided below. Review the CompositionException.Errors property for more detailed information.

1) No exports were found that match the constraint: 
ContractName    Itok.BusinessLogic.Interfaces.IFolderService
RequiredTypeIdentity    Itok.BusinessLogic.Interfaces.IFolderService

Resulting in: Cannot set import 'Itok.Web.Photos.Presenters.DefaultPresenter._folderService (ContractName="Itok.BusinessLogic.Interfaces.IFolderService")' on part 'Itok.Web.Photos.Presenters.DefaultPresenter'.

Element: Itok.Web.Photos.Presenters.DefaultPresenter._folderService (ContractName="Itok.BusinessLogic.Interfaces.IFolderService") --> Itok.Web.Photos.Presenters.DefaultPresenter
```

Here is the IFolderService.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Itok.Entities;

namespace Itok.BusinessLogic.Interfaces
{
    public interface IFolderService
    {
        List<Folder> GetFriendsFolders(Int32 AccountID);
        void DeleteFolder(Folder folder);
        List<Folder> GetFoldersByAccountID(Int32 AccountID);
        Folder GetFolderByID(Int64 FolderID);
        Int64 SaveFolder(Folder folder);
    }
}
```

And this is the exporting class definition, FolderService.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Itok.BusinessLogic.Interfaces;
using System.ComponentModel.Composition;
using Itok.DataAccess.Interfaces;
using Itok.Common;
using Itok.DataAccess;
using Itok.Interfaces;
using Itok.Entities;

namespace Itok.BusinessLogic
{    
    [Export(typeof(IFolderService))]    
    [Export(typeof(ICache))]
    public class FolderService : IFolderService
    {
        [Import]
        private IFriendRepository _friendRepository;
        [Import]
        private IFolderRepository _folderRepository;
        [Import]
        private ICache _cacheService;

        public FolderService()
        {
            MEFManager.Compose(this);
        }

        public List<Folder> GetFriendsFolders(Int32 AccountID)
        {
            List<Friend> friends = _friendRepository.GetFriendsByAccountID(AccountID);
            List<Folder> folders = _folderRepository.GetFriendsFolders(friends);
            folders.OrderBy(f => f.CreateDate).Reverse();
            return folders;
        }

         public void DeleteFolder(Folder folder)
        {   
            if (_cacheService.Exists(folder.AccountID.ToString()))
            {
                _cacheService.Delete(folder.AccountID.ToString());
            }

            _folderRepository.DeleteFolder(folder);
        }

        public List<Folder> GetFoldersByAccountID(int AccountID)
        {        
            List<Folder> cachedFolders = _cacheService.Get(AccountID.ToString()) as List<Folder>;
            if (cachedFolders != null)
            {
                return cachedFolders;
            }
            else
            {
                cachedFolders = _folderRepository.GetFoldersByAccountID(AccountID);
                _cacheService.Set(AccountID.ToString(), cachedFolders);
                return cachedFolders;
            }
        }

        public Folder GetFolderByID(Int64 FolderID)
        {
            return _folderRepository.GetFolderByID(FolderID);
        }

        public Int64 SaveFolder(Folder folder)
        {
            return _folderRepository.SaveFolder(folder);
        }
    }
}
```

I thank you prior to any help for saving my time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message means that MEF is looking for a class that is exported with the interface `IFolderService` but there isn't one in the container.

To investigate this, firstly check that there is a class that exports that interface and if there is, then look into whether that class being picked up by the container or not and thirdly, if neither of those resolve the issue, look into whether the class that is exported with the interface `IFolderService` has some other imports that can't be satisfied.

Comment: @بابکخلیفهسلطان look at the code for when the container is created, you should be able to debug the container to see which types are in it. Is this a new problem? I.e. has this container been working before? I often find that it is easiest/quickest to see what changes have been made and go through trying to find what imports/exports have been changed and try to spot the problem that way.

Comment: Thanks for the response: First: An export class does exist; Second: how may I make sure if the class is being picked up? And for the third case, the export class has got three more imports, with the same problem. So what the point of this later is?

Comment: This is probably the point. The container was working before. I was optimizing the app, so upgraded it adding a new project (Entities) to the solution and changed using Itok.DataAccess to using Itok.Entities. I think I should have been more careful about this. Any suggestion to rectify the issue?

Comment: @بابکخلیفهسلطان I would look at how the container is set up, it might be that it isn't including your new projects. If you can't get to the bottom of it, it might be easier to raise a new question for that though with some of the code from where the container is setup.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found the Solution for the problem. It has got has nothing to do directly with IFolderService that MEF was pointing to. The App has dependencies on a component (FolderService) in the business logic, which in turn is dependent upon an interface ICache, and an implementation wrapper, Cache.cs. ICache, specified by a contract name Itok.Interfaces.ICache, had been exported FOUR times (on just one Import). This was left unnoticed while I was trying to scale the solution. MEF couldn't tell which Export to use. The real problem is that MEF was pointing to a class two levels upper the chain!

Thanks TomDoesCode for looking at the problem, and I hope this will help others who'll get a similar problem.

A long term solution for this problem would be if you have many Exports that will satisfy an Import, you'll probably have two options:

I) Change the [Import] with [ImportMany]. Then during runtime, decide which import to use for the contract. Ask yourself if just picking up the first available, or using one at a time in random.

II) Use [ImportMany] in conjunction with Metadata in order to decide which Import to use.